# View refresh issue on Android 2.0+

Tags: android

I have have an Activity where I would like to hide some elements based on user selection of certain options on same screen. I'm using View.GONE to complete take view off the screen layout if particular option is selected. 
So this results in some of the UI components move upward.
And this seems working fine till Android 1.6. When UI components are moved upward remaining area at bottom is cleared properly. 
But on 2.1/2.2 device/emulator this bottom area is not getting cleared and components are visible at their old location and new location with some overlap.

Calls to requestLayout()/ refreshDrawableState() also does not have any effect.

My xml layout component nesting is something like below:

ScrollView

```
 RaidoGroup

 LinearLayout

    View1

    View2

    View3

    View4

    View5
```

Any clues ?

Comment: device memory does not look like low. Everything else works smoothly. And this is the case even if only one application is running .